# Migration from log4j v1 to log4j v2

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I would like to point out in advance that I am not a JAVA developer (I am a frontend developer) , that is why I am starting this query.
Java application from our customer is compiled with J2SE 1.4.2 and the application uses log4j 1.2.8, the customer would like to switch to log4j v2 and in the documentation I found information that log4j v2 uses java from version 6 onwards, more precisely

Log4j 2.3.2 (for Java 6), 2.12.4 (for Java 7), or 2.17.1 (for Java 8 and later)

If we switch to Log4j 2.3.2, are we able to compile the application to J2SE 1.4 or 1.6? We cannot upgrade the application to a higher version than 1.6.

I have also read that you can migrate using bridge, but here I can't find what version the application compiles then.
[migration.html](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#Log4j1.2Bridge)

Thank you for any reply

Answer (score 1):

Ability to compile the application to J2SE 1.4 or 1.6 is beyond using log4j 2.3.2, is about your actual code and your dependencies, first of all. I can't find reference about the possibility to use log4j 2.3 with Java 1.4, but I'm pretty sure you cant so the migration to Java 1.6 seems mandatory.

When Java release a major version, it's always bring some breaking change with it, you have to find them and fix in your code, and that's the easy part. The hard part is making sure that your current dependencies work properly with the target Java version, and if not, finding equivalents, which will require some integration work.

The reasons behind the customer's choice are not known, but this particular intervention seems to me to be out of place, given the old age of the code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I may ask a stupid question, but as I write above I am not a java developer. I'm trying to find out if this is possible or not .... If the application is going to use log4j 2.3 then we compile the application using J2SE 1.6?

Comment: JRE 1.0 through 8 are mostly backward compatible. The breaking changes started with Java 11 (removal of JAXB and other modules).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz for that reason I said "that's the easy part", but don't be too much confident about, I've migrating a lot of programs from 1.6 to 1.8 some years ago and most of them do not needed to be touch, instead some I had to fix some issues or behavior changes !

Answer (score 1):

In a Java project there are multiple version numbers to consider:

- the version of the compile time environment (JDK),
- the version of the runtime environment (JVM/JRE),
- the version of the generated bytecode: this sets a minimum version for the compile time and runtime environment.

If your client switches to `log4j-1.2-api` version 2.22.1, he:

- needs a JDK 8 or later to compile this application,
- he still can compile the application into 1.4 bytecode (but why?),
- needs a JVM/JRE 8 or later to run the application.

I seriously doubt your client is using anything older than JRE 8 to run its application: the extended support period for Java 7 ended two years ago, using JRE 7 or earlier has severe security implications.

**Remark**: Log4j 1.x had two parts: an API to issue log statements and a logging backend that delivers those statements to the appropriate files. It is entirely possible that your client didn't use Log4j 1.x as logging API (he used Apache Commons Logging for example). If this is the case, he doesn't even need to recompile the application, he just needs to add `log4j-core`, a configuration file and the appropriate bridges as runtime dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the information you passed on. 

The only information I have is that during development (if log4j v2 will be used) the application must be compiled preferably with J2SE 1.4.2 (they use Oracle JDeveloper for development see screen), or they can switch to J2SE 1.6

https://postimg.cc/V0MNSsXQ

Comment: If the problem is the build tool, they can compile against an archaic version of Log4j ([`log4j-over-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.5.0) version 1.5.0 is ideal, since it provides only methods that are **fully** supported by `log4j-1.2.-api`) and ship the application with `log4j-1.2-api`.